# Attempt to call dll function from matlab causing crash

Tags: c, matlab, dll, shared-libraries, loadlibrary

I'm trying to use a third-party external DLL (from usbmicro) within MATLAB, but it keeps crashing MATLAB. This is from the documentation indicating the syntax of the function call from within a C program:

```
int USBm_About( char *about );
```

I tried this MATLAB script (yes it's very kludgy, I'm a MATLAB noob):

```
>> loadlibrary('USBm.dll','USBmAPI.h')
>> libfunctions('USBm')
>> s='sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss';
>> st=strcat(s,s,s,s);
>> vp = libpointer('voidPtr',[int8(st) 0]);
>> result=calllib('USBm','USBm_About',vp)
```

and this one:

```
>> loadlibrary('USBm.dll','USBmAPI.h')
>> libfunctions('USBm')
>> s='sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss';
>> st=strcat(s,s,s,s);
>> vp=libpointer('cstring',st);
>> result=calllib('USBm','USBm_About',vp)
```

In both cases, the `calllib()` call causes MATLAB to crash with a segmentation fault.

The version of MATLAB is 7.10; the OS is Windows Vista.

---

#### Update:

Here's a screenshot of libfunctionsview USBm:
[image: screenshot]

Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef FILE_USBmAPI_h
#define FILE_USBmAPI_h


// Prototypes for this DLL.
// These are the API functions available to the .dll user.


// Discovery routine
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_FindDevices(void);

// Return info about devices
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_NumberOfDevices(void);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DeviceValid(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DeviceVID(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DevicePID(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DeviceDID(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DeviceFirmwareVer(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DeviceMfr(unsigned char, char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DeviceProd(unsigned char, char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DeviceSer(unsigned char, char *);

// General USBmicro U4xx device access
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_ReadDevice(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_SetReadTimeout(unsigned int);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_WriteDevice(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_CloseDevice(unsigned char);

// DLL string info access
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_RecentError(char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_ClearRecentError(void);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DebugString(char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Copyright(char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_About(char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Version(char *);



// General U4x1 device functions
// -----------------------------

// Port initialization
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_InitPorts(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_InitPortsU401(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_InitPortsU421(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_InitPortsU451(unsigned char);

// Port/bit reading and writing
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_WriteA(unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_WriteB(unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_WriteABit(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_WriteBBit(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_ReadA(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_ReadB(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_SetBit(unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_ResetBit(unsigned char, unsigned char);

// Port direction
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionA(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionAOut(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionAIn(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionAInPullup(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionB(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionBOut(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionBIn(unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_DirectionBInPullup(unsigned char);

// Strobbing a byte of data
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_StrobeWrite(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_StrobeRead(unsigned char, unsigned char *, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_StrobeWrite2(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_StrobeRead2(unsigned char, unsigned char *, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_StrobeWrites(unsigned char, unsigned char *, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_StrobeReads(unsigned char, unsigned char *, unsigned char *);

// Reading pin-change latches
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_ReadLatches(unsigned char, unsigned char *);

// LCD routines
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_InitLCD(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_LCDCmd(unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_LCDData(unsigned char, unsigned char);

// SPI routines
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_InitSPI(unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_SPIMaster(unsigned char, unsigned char *, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_SPISlaveWrite(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_SPISlaveRead(unsigned char, unsigned char *, unsigned char *);

// 2-wire routines
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Wire2Control(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Wire2Data(unsigned char, unsigned char *);

// Stepper routine
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Stepper(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);

// 1-wire routines
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Reset1Wire(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Write1Wire(unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Read1Wire(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Write1WireBit(unsigned char, unsigned char);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_Read1WireBit(unsigned char, unsigned char *);




#endif // multiple inclusion prevention

// End of file
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

#### Update:

I tried changing this line:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int USBm_About(char *);
```

to this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int USBm_About(char *);
```

in the header file, and then restarting MATLAB. I ran my code again and MATLAB still crashes.

Comment: How would we be able to work this out without USBmAPI.h and without knowing the rules of engagement for USBm_About?

Comment: This was in the original post: int USBm_About( char *about ); And then I just added a screenshot of the output from "libfunctionsview USBm". If you need more info, just ask for it.

Comment: similar question: [Passing pointer argument in MATLAB to a C-DLL function foo(char**)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445054/passing-pointer-argument-in-matlab-to-a-c-dll-function-foochar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the standard problem that your include file needs to have

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

when you are building the .dll but Matlab (or whichever project uses your .dll) needs to have:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
```

when you are including it.

This is why people usually have the following macro:

```
#ifdef USBMAPIEXPORTS 
#define USBMAPIDECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define USBMAPIDECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

and then on your functions in your header you write:

```
extern "C" USBMAPIDECLSPEC int USBm_FindDevices(void);
```

and you need to have `USBMAPIEXPORTS` defined when you build the .dll (but not when you use it in Matlab.)

Note that this is not a problem with Matlab.  [This is the standard way to use a .dll.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999/what-is-the-difference-between-dllexport-and-dllimport)
Did you try this?

Comment: The dll came from a third party. I don't have the source. So from what you're seeing, the dll in it's current form won't work with matlab?

Comment: Seems to me like whomever gave you the include file didn't do it right. I'd modify the include file `USBmAPI.h` to another file (make a backup first) so that whenever you see `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` change it to `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)`. (Alternately, you can use define the preprocessor block I wrote above and then write `extern "C" USBMAPIDECLSPEC`. Make sure you **don't** define `USBMAPIEXPORTS` if you do this.)

Comment: I'd also tell the provider of your .dll and .h file to, in the future, do things like I said in my original response. They should be the ones defining `USBMAPIEXPORTS` when they build. It's standard and saves loads of headaches.  Just to be clear, they built the .dll right, they just didn't make it easy for you to include.

Comment: I tried replacing all the dllexports with dllimport but still getting the same result. I also tried USBm_Copyright and that also causes a segmentation violation.

Comment: I see OP also posted on MATLAB Answers: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/6198-attempt-to-call-external-dll-function-causing-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the DLL from [USBmicro](http://www.usbmicro.com/) website, and tried to [use it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f23224dfi7.html) by calling [`loadlibrary()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/loadlibrary.html). Unfortunately, this crashed my MATLAB session as you said..

After some [research](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/data/1-671ZZL.html), I came to find out that the way this DLL exposes its functions is not compatible with the calling convention that MATLAB expects (cdecl vs. stdcall).

Here is how I fixed the header file:

```
#ifndef FILE_USBmAPI_h
#define FILE_USBmAPI_h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// ...
int __stdcall USBm_About(char *);
int __stdcall USBm_Version(char *);
// ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Now you can call any of the exported functions. Example:

```
%# load library and see exported functions signatures
if ~libisloaded('USBm')
    loadlibrary('USBm.dll','USBmAPI.h')
    libfunctions('USBm','-full')
end

%# call the function: `int USBm_About(char *)`
str = repmat(' ',1,100);                           %# allocate buffer
pStr = libpointer('stringPtr',str);                %# pointer to string
[num str2] = calllib('USBm','USBm_About',pStr)
clear pStr

%# unload library
unloadlibrary USBm
```

Note the signature of the function that MATLAB gives us:

```
[int32, cstring] USBm_About(cstring)
```

Interestingly, it has an additional output argument for this function. The reason is that MATLAB does not really support passing by reference, although you can create MATLAB arguments that are compatible with C pointers.

Thus if the C function return data in input arguments passed by reference, MATLAB will create additional output arguments to return these values (and any input arguments ending in `Ptr` or `PtrPtr`).

Now although the input argument `pStr` resembles a pointer to type char, it is not a true one as it does not contain the address of the MATLAB character array `str`. When the function executes, it returns the correct result, but does not modify the value in `str` (nor in this case `pStr` for that matters).

The output I got was:

```
>> num
num =
     0

>> str2
str2 =
 USBm.dll by USBmicro L.L.C. (www.usbmicro.com). Supports: U401, U421
```