# return array from c++ dll to matlab

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, dll, loadlibrary

I am trying to build a DLL in C++ and call it from MATLAB by using `loadlibrary` and `calllib` instructions. It works for one value and it return a value normally, but now I am trying to return a whole array from C++ DLL to MATLAB as an output of a function.

As you know C++ usually return the arrays as pointers but this don't work with MATLAB ...
I searched for that at the internet and they are using some MEX function but it is not clear ...

Can you explain how to return an array from C++ DLL to MATLAB `calllib` and how should we return it from C++ code ?

Comment: I think it is different or I didn't understand it ...

Comment: Thank you for reply
I tried to return a pointer to double but not worked
please write a line code so I can understand how should the function work ...
also I am calling this function from dll library not from mex directly ....

Comment: @EitanT: I think the OP is trying to use `loadlibrary`, not write a MEX function. Although that is a viable option as well to integrate with a C/C++

Comment: @Amro Ah, retracting my comments then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a DLL that exposes the following C function:

```
void getData(double *x, const int len)
{
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        x[i] = i;
    }
}
```

It takes an array already allocated an its length, and fills it with incremental values.

In MATLAB, first we [load the library](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html):

```
>> loadlibrary('mydll.dll', 'mydll.h')
>> libfunctions mydll -full

Functions in library mydll:

doublePtr getData(doublePtr, int32)
```

To call the exposed function, we use [`libpointer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/libpointer.html):

```
>> p = libpointer('doublePtr', zeros(1,10))  % initialize array of 10 elements
p =
libpointer
>> get(p)
       Value: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    DataType: 'doublePtr'
>> calllib('mydll', 'getData', p, 10)        % call C function
>> get(p)
       Value: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
    DataType: 'doublePtr'
```

we could also simply pass regular vectors and MATLAB will take care of marshalling:

```
>> x = calllib('mydll', 'getData', zeros(1,10), 10)
x =
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

note that in [this case](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/working-with-pointers.html), the modified array will be returned as an output (since builtin types will not be modified in-place).

Comment: you could also write the function so that it allocates the memory itself. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7446744/97160) for an example (works with strings, but the concept is similar). Also, as an alternative, you could write a MEX-function that wraps the C/C++ DLL instead of using `loadlibrary` approach

Comment: Thank you very much ...
can I apply it to 2d-Array ? (actually I am the c programmer and I don't know a lot about matlab... But it is the work :)...)

Comment: @user130227: It's easy to try, try calling the above as: `x = calllib('mydll', 'getData', zeros(2,5), 10)`... So it would apply to any dimensional array, just remember that MATLAB uses [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order). Even if it didn't you could always pass flat 1D arrays and then `reshape` the result in MATLAB as 2D matrix