# Failing to marshal char** between native x32 shared library and matlab

Tags: matlab, shared-libraries, marshalling, native, loadlibrary

I'm trying to call a function in a native shared library from matlab using `loadlibrary` and `calllib` but I'm failing to obtain a string that is allocated from inside the library as char**.

Here is the (**simplified**) code of the native library:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)

DllExport __int32 __stdcall MyFunction1()
{
    return 42;
}

DllExport __int32 __stdcall MyFunction2(__int32 handle, const char* format, char** info)
{
    *info = _strdup(format);
    return handle;
}
```

And here is the (**test**) code from matlab side:

```
function [] = test()
%[
    loadlibrary('MyDll', @prototypes);

    try

        % Testing function 1
        val1 = calllib('MyDll', 'MyFunction1');
        disp(val1); % ==> ok the display value is 42

        % Testing function 2 
        info = libpointer('stringPtrPtr', {''});
        val2 = calllib('MyDll', 'MyFunction2', 666, 'kikou', info);    
        disp(val2); % ==> ok the value is 666
        disp(info.Value{1}); % ==> ko!! The value is still '' instead of 'kikou'

    catch
    end

    unloadlibrary('MyDll');
%]

%% --- Define prototypes for 'MyDll'
function [methodinfo, structs, enuminfo] = prototypes()
%[
    % Init
    ival = {cell(1,0)}; 
    fcns = struct('name',ival,'calltype',ival,'LHS',ival,'RHS',ival,'alias',ival);
    structs = []; enuminfo = []; fcnNum = 0;

    % Declaration for '__int32 __stdcall MyFunction1()'
    fcnNum = fcnNum+1; fcns.name{fcnNum} = 'MyFunction1'; fcns.calltype{fcnNum} = 'stdcall'; fcns.LHS{fcnNum} = 'int32'; fcns.RHS{fcnNum} = {};

    % Declaration for '__int32 __stdcall MyFunction2(__int32 handle, const char* format, char** info)'
    fcnNum = fcnNum+1; fcns.name{fcnNum} = 'MyFunction2'; fcns.calltype{fcnNum} = 'stdcall'; fcns.LHS{fcnNum} = 'int32'; fcns.RHS{fcnNum} = { 'int32', 'cstring', 'stringPtrPtr'};

    methodinfo = fcns;
%]
```

As you can see from `prototypes` sub-function, `handle` is marshaled as `int32`, `format` as `cstring` and `info` as `stringPtrPtr`. This is what by default perl's script creates from 'MyDll.h' and also what is suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445054/passing-pointer-argument-in-matlab-to-a-c-dll-function-foochar).

I've tried many other marshaling types but could not figure out how to obtain correct value for `info`.

NB: It is not reported here, but the native library also defines a function to free the memory allocated for `info` argument. My Matlab version is 7.2.0.232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7818584/97160), I discovered that input arguments of pointer types were not modified in place, instead additional output arguments were returned containing a copy of any pointer type input with any changes.

You can see this fact with:

```
>> libfunctions MyDll -full

Functions in library MyDll:

[int32, cstring, stringPtrPtr] MyFunction2(int32, cstring, stringPtrPtr)
```

The weird thing is that when I just tried this again on the latest R2013a, input arguments are indeed modified. Something must have changed since then :)

So in your case, you should call:

```
info = libpointer('stringPtrPtr',{''});
[val,~,info2] = calllib('MyDll', 'MyFunction2', 666, 'kikou', info)
```

and check the output `info2`