# Difference between dllexport vs dllimport

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I've searched through some Microsoft tutorials and all related stackoverflow threads to find the right answer. None of them is clear enough for me.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999/what-is-the-difference-between-dllexport-and-dllimport) still leaves some doubt.

*"__declspec( dllexport ) - The class or function so tagged will be exported from the DLL it is built in"*

vs.

*"__declspec( dllimport ) - The class or function so tagged will be imported from a DLL"*

Well, it hardly makes sense, because what does it mean "import from DLL" and "export from DLL". You can either **export from** and **import to** something, or **import from** and **export to** something.

My understanding is:
dllexport is used to specify that I want to load this code to the DLL I'm creating, whereas dllimport is used to tell the compiler that I'd like to make use of code from a DLL.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use something from a dll, you include the good .h file, which will contain __declspec( dllimport ) ( often done with a #define macro for switching accordingly between export and import when we are compiling).

As a consequence you will import FROM the dll which provides this .h file.

On the contrary when you compile this dll, the .h file contains __declspec( dllexport ), telling the compiler/linker to do the job for exporting such part FROM our dll.

Comment: Maybe this will let me understand it better - when the export thing actually happens? While creating a DLL, or using it?

Comment: When you compile the dll, you expose the functions and classes that can be used by another dll or exe. If you look at the .lib file generated when compiling the dll, you see what is accessible from that dll you have just compiled.

Comment: So dllexport puts the functions in the exports table inside DLL, making them available for other programs. And other programs can load these functions using dllimport. Is that correct?

Comment: Almost. dllimport is what you use in conjunction with __declspec to have the linker reference to the object/function you want to use. This is when you compile the .h header file containing the definition you want to use in your own program. The actual loading of theses function is done at the dll loading stage, and this stage is not compilation nor linking.

Comment: I've decided to play with it a litte, according to this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx
The funny things is that even if I get rid of the "#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) " line, it's all working well. Even if I rebuild the project. Is it Visual studio 2013 fixing things automatically? Or me not gettig it yet?

Comment: I don't have all your code, so I could not say. However there is an automagical dll linking function since 2010. This is the way Boost C++ libraries can be loaded automagically since then. Used it once only, so I won't say anything more about it :-)

Comment: To be more precise - no matter what I put inside X and Y places (I've tried all combinations of dllexport and dllimport) in my dll header, it works equally well in the project using that dll. .lib files are identical in all cases.
#ifdef DLLPROJECT_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(X) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(Y) 
#endif

Probably I would have to test it in some older Visual Studio though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read those:

[Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d(VS.80).aspx)

[Importing into an Application Using __declspec(dllimport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy(VS.80).aspx)